# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED while using nginx for flask-socketio

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a server code that uses flask socketio. The server is started by the command: 1gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 module:app`

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name A.B.C.D;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

This is from the official documentation of Flask Socket io, [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

My two endpoints are working just fine. However, the socket endpoint runs fine when run manually(i.e. me running the command: `python index.py`), the problem comes when I want to run it via nginx and gunicorn.

With nginx:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have put code which is from the documentation, confs from the documentation and nothing worked.

Comment: I am having this exact issue when deploying to an Amazon AWS EC2 instance. Thank you for asking -- hopefully we can get an expert response soon.